# Django using template input data to create new objects

Tags: django-views, django-templates

Due to my lack of skills I think I overcomplicate and would like to get input for a simple solution. I'm creating kind of a web shop template. I have a service work order that I would like to add parts to. I have a decent looking template where I can list all parts that fits a machine model and then filter through them.

One Workorder many Parts (So I have one separate class for all parts objects for workorder). SO to avoid to have to update part number by part number, using create view. I have tried to use a listview where I try to select all parts at the same time.

In my CBV I define the filtering and get a context "Partslist" with all parts to show in table. In the template I have created an input fields qty. I.e. all part in the "Partslist" gets a "qty" inputfields.

In my post or save definition can I simply catch all input fields data with a self.request.GET statement somehow, or could I use the context "Partslist" to iterate through the fields?

models.py

```
class WorkOrderParts(models.Model):
    wo_num = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Order Number')
    wo_pa_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Part Number')
    wo_pa_qty_def = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3,decimal_places=0,verbose_name='Qty Planned for')

class Parts(models.Model):
    pa_number = models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name='Part Number')
    pa_group1 = models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name='Group of Parts')
    pa_group2 = models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name='2:nd Group of Parts')
    pa_fits = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='models that part fit to (BRAND-MODEL)'),default=list, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
class WO_PartCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/login'
    template_name = 'AddPart.html'
    model = WorkOrderParts


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        model = 'my machine model'
        qs=Parts.objects.filter(pa_fits__icontains=model)
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Partslist'] = qs
        return context
    
   def post(self):
   ??? This is where I want to take all parts with input qty>0 and update new objects into WorkOrderParts.
```

AddPart.html

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-left">Part Number</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Quantity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            {% for item in Partslist %}
           <tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">
                        {% autoescape off %}{{item.pa_number}}{% endautoescape %}<br>
                    </td>

                    <td class="text-left">
                       <input type="number" method="GET" name="{{ item.pa_number }}-Qty"/>
                    </td>
                  
            </tr>
          </tbody>
```

I hope I have been able to explain enough for someone to understand me.The reason why I use a table is simply that I have much more data in there that I want to display.

Answer (score 0):

OK I know there is most probably better ways to solve this. But since I at least was able to find out something that worked, I thought I would share it with others.

It at least solved my immediate need to grab input fields from a dynamic list and do something with it.

views.py

```py
    class AddPartTest(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/login'
    template_name = 'AddPart.html' 
    model = Parts
    form_class = Add_Parts2 ##including selected fields

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        order = self.kwargs.get('str')
        wo = WorkOrder_main.objects.get(order=order)
        model = wo.wo_machine_model
        qs=Parts.objects.filter(pa_fits__icontains=model)
        first_contains_query = self.request.GET.get('pa_group1')
        if is_valid_queryparam(first_contains_query):
            qs=qs.filter(pa_group1=first_contains_query)
            second_contains_query = self.request.GET.get('pa_group2')
        if is_valid_queryparam(second_contains_query):
            qs=qs.filter(pa_group2= second_contains_query)
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['Partslist'] = qs
        return context

    def post (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order = self.kwargs.get('str')
        context = self.get_context_data()
        Partslist_x = context['Partslist']
        Parts_num_list = Partslist_x.values_list('pa_number', flat=True)
        for part in Parts_num_list:
            qty = part + 'Qty'
            Qty = self.request.POST.get(qty)
            if int(Qty)==0:
                pass
            else:
                WorkOrderParts.objects.create(
                                wo_num=order,
                                wo_pa_number=part,
                                wo_pa_qty_def=Qty,
                            )
        path='where I want to end up'
        return redirect (path)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site. Focus on explaining why your answer is a good one, and don't worry about personal issues.